# How to design a simple CRUD REST API

Tags: java, api, rest, grails

I'm designing a simple CRUD REST API. This is my first time so I wanted to get some feedback on whether my design makes sense.

I'm utilizing the HTTP methods: GET, POST, DELETE, and UPDATE . The API will consume and fetch data in JSON format. The sample URL will be such as this:

```
GET (list): curl http://<domain>/myapp/rest/v1/colors
POST: curl -XPOST http://<domain>/myapp/rest/v1/colors -d '{
       "name": "red",
       "shade": "light"
      }'
GET (single item): curl http://<domain>/myapp/rest/v1/colors/2
DELETE: curl -XDELETE http://<domain>/myapp/rest/v1/colors/2
etc...
```

**Question**

After the POST request a record will be created in the database. So, should the POST request return the ID of the newly created record? So that ID can be used in `UPDATE, DELETE and GET (single item)`?

Comment: It depends how you have designed your rest service. Ya , a POST request can receive response body.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I understand that a POST can receive a body. But can I send a response after the request has been processed and say, for example, that newly created record has an ID of `659`

Comment: Yeah you can use those ids if those are in sync with your database.

Comment: A pragmatic answer would be: Yes, return the ID of the newly created item (auto-incremented primary key?). Whether or not that is in-line with REST, thus what the HTTP standard prescribes is debatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) defines the following for POST:

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location header (see section 14.30).

So this essentially means:

- You should return `201 Created` as status code
- You should return a `Location` header, pointing to the URI of the newly created resource
- You can optionally include a representation of the resource in the POST response body to free the client from having to issue another `GET` request against the value obtained from the `Location` header.

Comment: nice. so that third bullet means I can simply return the newly created ID

Comment: No. First, the URI *is* the ID (hence the name). Second, I wrote "a representation of the resource", this means it's essentially the same you'd get if you followed the link in the `Location` header, read: the JSON you originally sent in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The POST should return a redirect to the new url for the single item.

You probably want to loose the version identifier of the urls.

Instead design your representations and the clients in a way that handles various versions gracefully. For example a client should not depend on a specific format, but only on the attributes it actually needs.

What is kind of missing from your description is the HATEOAS principle, i.e. the client shouldn't hard code any URLs, but find the URLs for further actions inside the representation of other entities. Since you don't show an example document for the results returned by the URLs, we can't tell if you did that in a nice way.

Check out [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/hypermedia-apis-with-spring), it explains the topic and also mentions some Spring Library helpful for implementing it.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the HATEOAS principle. btw even though tags are missing I'm using grails to accomplish this. I'll add the tag. So, instead of returning just the ID, the post should return a complete URL for the single item i.e. 'http://<domain>/myapp/rest/v1/colors/2'